# Append multiline tab delimited text form bash script with EOF, EOT, EOL

Tags: linux, bash, multiline, eof

I want to insert after a specific string occurrence a multi-line text.
The expected output is:

```
configuration options:
<tab>option 1
<tab>option 2
<tab>option 3
<tab>option 4
<tab>option 5
<tab>option 6
<tab>option 7
<tab>option 8
<tab>option 9
<tab>option 10
<tab>option 11
<tab>option 12
```

All lines except from the first are delimited with a tab.
I don't want to do this with several echo commands.
I would prefer EOF, EOT, EOL but these do not write the tabs.

Currently I use that:

```
  cat >> /etc/conf/conf.conf <<-EOF
  <tab>configuration options
  <tab><tab>option 1
  <tab><tab>option 2
  <tab><tab>option 3
  <tab><tab>option 4
  <tab><tab>option 5
  <tab><tab>option 6
  <tab><tab>option 7
  <tab><tab>option 8
  <tab><tab>option 9
  <tab><tab>option 10
  <tab><tab>option 11
  <tab><tab>option 12
  EOF
```

But the second tab is ignored and not written to my file.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Provide a minimal input and verifiable expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the dash (`-`) from this line:

```
cat >> /etc/conf/conf.conf <<-EOF
```

And, maybe, use a better name for EOF:

```
cat >> /etc/conf/conf.conf <<_list_of_options_
configuration options
<tab>option 1
<tab>option 2
<tab>option 3
<tab>option 4
<tab>option 5
<tab>option 6
<tab>option 7
<tab>option 8
<tab>option 9
<tab>option 10
<tab>option 11
<tab>option 12
_list_of_options_
```

Answer (score 0):

bash allows the following syntax, similar to EOF where the string in single quotes is not modified at all:

```
cat >> /etc/conf/conf.conf <<<'configuration options
<tab>option 1
<tab>option 2
<tab>option 3
<tab>option 4
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it out as a combination of the above answer:
In order to keep the tab delimiter I had to remove the "-" before EOF and remove one tab from each line:

```
cat >> /etc/conf/conf.conf <<EOF
configuration options
<tab>option 1
<tab>option 2
<tab>option 3
<tab>option 4
<tab>option 5
<tab>option 6
<tab>option 7
<tab>option 8
<tab>option 9
<tab>option 10
<tab>option 11
EOF
```